# How can I access to this methods in python?

Tags: python

Im trying to learn about POO in Python. I have read about that and I would like to access to methods from some example codes.

Does anybody know how to acces to distance method? the code is below.

I have tried writing **obj=Site(value1, value2)**,   **obj.distance(value1, value2)**

Can anybody help me?

```
class Site(object):

def __init__(self,x=0.0,y=0.0,sitenum=0):
    self.x = x
    self.y = y
    self.sitenum = sitenum


def dump(self):
    print "Site #%d (%g, %g)" % (self.sitenum,self.x,self.y)

def __cmp__(self,other):
    if self.y < other.y:
        return -1
    elif self.y > other.y:
        return 1
    elif self.x < other.x:
        return -1
    elif self.x > other.x:
        return 1
    else:
        return 0

def distance(self,other):
    dx = self.x - other.x
    dy = self.y - other.y
    return math.sqrt(dx*dx + dy*dy)
```

Comment: please re-indent your class definition.

Comment: How did you manage to write the code without understanding how it works?

Comment: Im learning from example codes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Site.distance requires "other" which means another instance of that class.
Try:

```
s1 = Site(...)
s2 = Site(...)
distance = s1.distance(s2)
```